# How to manually log exception to be used with ereporter?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception

I use [ereporter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/python/recording_exceptions_with_ereporter) in my GAE app to be informed about all **uncaught** exceptions thru email. But I also would like to be informed other (handled) issues, so, I use the following code:

```
if something:
    pass
else:
    logging.exception('something is wrong')
```

But ereporter fails with such cases with `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ereporter/ereporter.py", line 227, in emit
signature = self.__GetSignature(record.exc_info)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ereporter/ereporter.py", line 175, in __GetSignature
fulltype = '%s.%s' % (ex_type.__module__, ex_type.__name__)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

I understand why it happens - there is no real Exception. But is there any way still to log such cases with ereporter?

Comment: Try `adding exc_info= sys.exc_info()` after message in `logging.exception` call

Comment: @TimHoffman, it will return 3 `None`s (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info), let me try.. Thanks.

Comment: @TimHoffman, I've just tried that - it doesn't help, the same error happens.

Comment: @TimHoffman: that is what `logging.exception()` *already does* when you don't pass in `exc_info` yourself. That's *why* the ereporter traceback happens, because there is no exception here to log in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said yourself - there's no exception to report. Since `ereporter` seems to *only* report exceptions, the solution is clear:

```
if something:
    pass
else:
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except Exception:
         logging.exception('something is wrong')
```